# How to avoid string repetition in Zend redirect methods?

Tags: php, zend-framework, refactoring

I have a Zend project with a lot of controllers and actions using the method

```
$this->_redirect('/controller_name/action_name');
```

for redirecting to other actions after data processing. I've observed that this creates a lot of "magic strings" that hurts the DRY principle: if I change a controller or action name I'd have to change this redirection code in all actions that use it. I'd like to know if there is a better way in Zend to avoid this. I've thought about creating constants for all controllers and action names, like this:

```
$this->_redirect(HOME_CONTROLLER_INDEX);
```

But I think this approach isn't very good. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on why you don't want to use a `define()`? It seems like a pretty good idea.

Comment: I think it would pollute the namespace with too many constants, more than it is already.

Comment: If not defines, then some extending, I'd say. Extend either the controller (not recommended) or create an action helper (you'd have to rewrite a lot of your current redirects) that would accept a string key (like `HOME_CONTROLLER_INDEX`) and then use its internal lookup table to see what URL this should redirect to. You'd have to maintain and update the lookup table only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use const instead

```
class DefaultController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
  const IndexAction = '/controller/action/';

  ...
  $this->_redirect(DefaultController::IndexAction);
}
```

Or SplEnum. See: http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.splenum.php

Comment: This works good but I had to put the `includePaths.controllers` directive in the application.ini.

Answer (score 1):

Your option of defining constant would be a viable one if you don't plan on modifying your router (since you are using the "compiled" url).

```
$this->_redirect('/controller/action');
```

Otherwise, you could rely on a few private methods that call the `redirector` action helper.

```
public function redirectControllerAction()
{
    $this->_helper->redirector('action', 'controller');
}
```

This way you can have all your redirections localized in your `controllers`.

If you have to maintain your code in the future you have all your specifics redirection grouped together and  you won't cluter your code with a lot of constants that could hinder readability and make it complex to maintain.

You could also use the controller method to send message to your user using the flash messenger without much effort.

```
public function redirectControllerAction()
{
    $this->_helper->flashMessenger('You have been redirected to a better location');
    $this->_helper->redirector('action', 'controller');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the destination controller name, you can add this static method:

```
public static function getName() { return __CLASS__; }
```

(You need to add code to remove the controller suffix and call Zend_Filter_Word_xxx to perform inflection)

and use it like this:

```
$this->_redirect('/'.DefaultController::getName().'/action_name');
```